# May I use a smaller wattage resistor as mosfet's gate driver for a very short time?

Tags: resistors, thermal

In a H-Bridge circuit, i am using gate resistors on all the mosfets. 
My calculations for one of them, Gate voltage 4.5 V and Resistor 100 ohm gives me 45 mA, means 203 mW.

In a pulse of 16 us i need these numbers to charge/discharge the gate for total 310 ns, 1.94% of the cycle. I am safe using 250 mW SMD resistor.

If i will use a smaller resistor for example 82 ohm it will give me 54.88 mA and 247 mW for total charge/discharge time of 254 ns, 1.59% of the cycle.

May I continue to use a SMD resistor of 250 mW based on the short duration of use?

Comment: S = Siemens. s = seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With very short gate charge/discharge pulses, you need to consider the average power.

The energy dissipated in the resistor each time the gate capacitance is charged or discharged is equal to the energy stored in the gate capacitance (assuming an ideal driver), which means you don't have to worry about waveforms and suchlike.

Let's assume your 4.5v gate voltage is driving an effective 10nF gate capacitance. That's an energy of 4.5*4.5*10n/2 = 100nJ. If you're driving at 100kHz (say), then that's 200k transitions per second, or an average power of 200k*100n = 20mW. This is the power you need to handle when selecting a gate resistor size. Just substitute in your frequency and gate capacitance.

Comment: You are correct. I found in diodes calculator "Power MOSFET Gate Driver Calculator - Issue 1.2" for resistors power losses the formula = Switching Frequence x Total gate Charge x (Transistors base drive voltage - 0.8).  Replacing in the above formula the "Cate charge" with "Capacitance x "Voltage" results your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Don't guess. The pulse capability of the resistor should be in the datasheet or associated technical information. For example, from the [Panasonic manual](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDA0000/DMA0000COL11.pdf):

[image]

Note that no matter how low the duty cycle you must not exceed 15x the rated steady-state power dissipation dissipation (100 x 0.15) during the pulse, for the ERJ8G 0.25W series of parts. Personally, I would be more conservative than that.

Comment: The table you show is concerned with the voltage rating, not the power rating, but I agree that reading the data sheet usually answers questions. And when the data sheet doesn't answer a question, that supplier is possibly somewhat sketchy...

For the question above, the answer is in the formula: Pp = K*P*T/t, meaning that, for short pulses, acceptable power is inversely proportional to on time ratio. This makes sense, because the main reason for resistor power ratings, is heat dissipation, and heat buildup is "comparatively slow" at the levels we're talking about here.

Comment: I couldn't find such infos [here](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/esr-e-1139161.pdf) neither  [here](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/AOA0000C331-1141874.pdf) or [here](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/rcse3-1013761.pdf). Perhaps i don't know to decode this information.